# Extended bootstrapper application changing logo

Tags: installation, wix, burn, wix-extension

I used wix bootstrapper extended aplication and wixballextentionExt.dll for making radio button sellection but I can't change logo because ı cant use old ballextention.dll. How can I change logo with balextentionEXT. What is WixVariable ıd for logo ı find license and theme but cant find logo.

```
   <BootstrapperApplicationRef  Id="WixExtendedBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense"    >



  <Payload SourceFile="Logo.png"/>
  <Payload SourceFile="LogoSide.png"/>
  <Payload Name="1033\thm.wxl" Compressed="yes" SourceFile="1033\thm.wxl"   />
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>

<WixVariable Id="WixExtbaThemeXml" Value="thm.xml" />

<WixVariable Id="WixExtbaLicenseRtf" Value="Resources\EULA.rtf" />


<Variable Name="RadioClient" Type="numeric" Value="0" />
<Variable Name="RadioServer" Type="numeric" Value="0" />
<Variable Name="RadioFull" Type="numeric" Value="1" />
```

in the old balextention.dll I used this code but now ı cant use it.

```
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
       <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseUrl="Resources\EULA.rtf" ThemeFile="thm.xml"
          LicenseFile="Resources\EULA.rtf"

        LogoFile="Resources\icon.png"   LogoSideFile="Resources\icon.ico"                               
      />


      <Payload Name="1033\thm.wxl" SourceFile="1033\thm.wxl" />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find solution this is from BalCompiler.cs

```
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(launchTarget))
            {
                this.Core.CreateVariableRow(sourceLineNumbers, "LaunchTarget", launchTarget, "string", false, false);
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(launchTargetElevatedId))
            {
                this.Core.CreateVariableRow(sourceLineNumbers, "LaunchTargetElevatedId", launchTargetElevatedId, "string", false, false);
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(launchArguments))
            {
                this.Core.CreateVariableRow(sourceLineNumbers, "LaunchArguments", launchArguments, "string", false, false);
            }

            if (YesNoType.Yes == launchHidden)
            {
                this.Core.CreateVariableRow(sourceLineNumbers, "LaunchHidden", "yes", "string", false, false);
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(launchWorkingDir))
            {
                this.Core.CreateVariableRow(sourceLineNumbers, "LaunchWorkingFolder", launchWorkingDir, "string", false, false);
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(licenseFile))
            {
                this.Core.CreateWixVariableRow(sourceLineNumbers, "WixExtbaLicenseRtf", licenseFile, false);
            }

            if (null != licenseUrl)
            {
                this.Core.CreateWixVariableRow(sourceLineNumbers, "WixExtbaLicenseUrl", licenseUrl, false);
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(logoFile))
            {
                this.Core.CreateWixVariableRow(sourceLineNumbers, "WixExtbaLogo", logoFile, false);
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(logoSideFile))
            {
                this.Core.CreateWixVariableRow(sourceLineNumbers, "WixExtbaLogoSide", logoSideFile, false);
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(themeFile))
            {
                this.Core.CreateWixVariableRow(sourceLineNumbers, "WixExtbaThemeXml", themeFile, false);
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(localizationFile))
            {
                this.Core.CreateWixVariableRow(sourceLineNumbers, "WixExtbaThemeWxl", localizationFile, false);
            }
```

Now ı can client database and full installation with Wix extended application.